# Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\n

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, ansible

Getting error when i try to connect to hosts in ansible

I am able to ping ssh_connection in local host (ansible), but not in jenkins pipeline build.

I have tried almost everything.

```
----------
[FPipeline] Running shell script
+ ansible all -m ping -vvv
ansible 2.4.0.0
config file = /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FPipeline/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = 
[u'/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/plugins/modules', 
u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 
(Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
Using /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FPipeline/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 
KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-
mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 
ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/8a5a4c6a60 
localhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<192.168.219.131> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.219.131> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o 
ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o 
PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o 
PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 
ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/81147ff3f7 192.168.219.131 '/bin/sh 
-c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.219.131> (255, '', 'Host key verification failed.\r\n')
server1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification  
failed.\r\n", 
"unreachable": true
}
<localhost> (255, '', 'Host key verification failed.\r\n')
localhost | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification 
failed.\r\n", 
"unreachable": true
}

----------
```

Can you please help me regarding this...

Answer (score 21):

In your ansible  config file `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FPipeline/ansible.cfg` add below line and test it again.

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way to disable host key checking in `ansible` is by setting the `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` environment variable to `False`

`export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False`

[Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html#host-key-checking)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of disabling the host key check completely I would recommend to add all hosts once (you should verify the SSH fingerprints). You need to run these commands with the user who initiates the SSH connection (in your case probably the Jenkins user):

```
# remove any old fingerprints for the host
ssh-keygen -R server.example.com
# add SSH fingerprints for the host
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa,ed25519 -H server.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Was the machine rebuilt since it first connected to it?

If so you need to remove the host from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or add the following option to SSH: `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Jenkins ansible plugin.  Their documentation has an error for the host key checking, but [here is a full working example](https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/06/27/using-ansible-in-jenkins-ansible-plugin/):

And here's the important snippet with the resolution:

```
ansiColor('xterm') {
    ansiblePlaybook(
        playbook: './ansible/playbook.yml',
        inventory: '/tmp/inventory.ini',
        credentialsId: 'your-jenkins-pk-credential',
        disableHostKeyChecking: true,
        colorized: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins gives the option to disable the SSH host key check.

1. At the bottom of the build step, click [Advanced]
2. Check the box in front of "Disable the SSH host key check".

Answer (score -1):

For **Debian (Ubuntu)**

Check file permissions of the authorized_keys file

use this command to check the file permissions `sudo ls -ld /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

change the file permissions using this command `sudo chmod u=rw,og=r /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

That is it...